# R package updating problem on Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: r

In R, to use other packages, `Biocgenerics` should be updated from 0.22 to 0.23.3. But in Ubuntu the last version of `r-bioc-biocgenerics` is 0.22. I couldn't do the update from Ubuntu and R.

How can I update `Biocgenerics`?

Comment: close voters, I've edited the question to make it clearer what is being asked. IMO it wasn't unclear to begin with.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't be using theUbuntu repository for installing bioconductor packages.
Use the approach described on the Bioconductor page for [Biocgenerics](http://bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/BiocGenerics.html):

```
## try http:// if https:// URLs are not supported
source("https://bioconductor.org/biocLite.R")
biocLite("BiocGenerics")
```

Comment: yes I do. but on ubuntu the package is 0.22 version. Is it problem to update on R to 0.23.3? I cannot update anyway I could not find solution